# Java- redirecting input stream

Tags: java, inputstream

How do I redirect the input stream for a program so that it will run from the console as main > myProgram with no filename specified within the code? This is what I have so far.

```
public static void main (String[ ] args) throws IOException { 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in)); 
    while(in.next != null){
        in.read();
    }
}
```

I know it's going to be something to do with System.setIn but I have no clue as to how to write it so that it will detect a filename after Main > is typed.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase.

Comment: Why can't you just pipe the data in in the first place?

Comment: There's no need to call `setIn(...)` or anything of that sort. The System.in will refer to the file that was piped into your program without your doing anything.

Comment: What kind of thing do i need to add so that it will point to the file?

Comment: `java MyClass < myFile.txt` will send myFile.txt to your MyClass program, assuming that you have a MyClass.class file there.

Comment: That's what i've been doing. My question was how to make that command output text from the file

Comment: um, that's all it takes. Once you do that System.in represents the file.

Comment: Okay thanks. That explains why everyone keeps restating the question. Although for some reason when i do that, it doesnt read file contents, it just reprints Main > Filename

Answer (score 1):

Use standard `System.in` and `System.out` streams.

Comment: ... and on the command line, use greater than and less than signs for file i/o redirection. Something like: `java MyProgram < my.input > my.output`

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect the streams, it is the methods of the System class: setIn(), setOut(), setErr() , which will help.
now in order to redirect the stream you have to redirect it to the specific file type.

For instance if want to redirect the output stream, then you need to use the setOut(). the setOut() takes an object of print stream and print stream has a parameterized constructor which takes string, you will be providing the path in that manner.

here's the program which is linked to a test file.
whenever you call the println() method on it, the stream will redirect it to the test file instead of the output console in this case.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Redirect1 {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream("C:\\Users\\nEW u\\Desktop\\Test.txt"));

        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

And here is the program for the input stream:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.System;

public class Redirect {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        System.setIn(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\nEW u\\Desktop\\dev.txt"));
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s="";
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```